# Server memory upgrade of IBM servers - can I use non IBM memory?

Tags: memory, upgrade

We just receive some old servers IBM servers (DDR2 and DDR3). We want to use them to upgrade our Test Area. I see that there are second hand memory with very good prices. Can we upgrade with other ECC or it must be IBM (qualified)?

I've heard that Server vendors put some differences so you have to buy memory upgrade onlu from the original vendor.

Comment: Certainly there are cases where you have had to use vendor memory and that's still the case for disks on many systems but often you can use OEM memory of the exact same spec and it'll work fine - could void any warranty however.

Comment: 10x, @Chopper3. The servers are with expired warranty. They are taken from our Production Area. I just ask if there is general rule for IBM. I undersnad that they can be other issues, because we intend to buy just ECC ram with similar specs.

Comment: Check on like kingston, they got a system selector tool. If your server is listed I would be safe to order.

Answer (score 1):

Memory compatibility is always a toss-up, unless you get the OK from someone who's tried the exact same memory in the exact same system.

That being said, I haven't heard of a case where inserting incompatible memory caused the magic blue smoke to escape from a system. At worst, it won't POST or you get an unstable system.

So, try the off-brand memory and run a memory test to check for stability.